# Xamarin - tutorials reference missing identifier field

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I downloaded Xamarin a few days ago and started going through the tutorials but i cannot even complete a relatively simple tutorial

[Xamarin Tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_5_-_using_xcode,_interface_builder,_and_storyboards/)

I get to step "Create the UI" where on the StoryBoards it starts referring to an field called "Identifier" - i can not find this. Some posts i found on Stackoverflow suggest that this is now called Storyboard ID? However storyboard ID is not available on all objects. StoryboardID is only available for Controllers, in this specific tutorial it is trying to set a Table View Cell identifier (!??????).

The tutorial becomes completely useless then even from a basic understanding point of view because these IDs are used later on in the C# code.

I am almost certain that this problem is because of Xcode version changes between 4 and 5 or something however its incredibly frustrating for someone new to Xamarin when going through the basic tutorials that they don't make any sense when it relates to Xcode ):

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Identifier for Table View Cell. In the tutorial on the image you may notice that cell is selected. And also in the tutorial written that you should set Identifier to retrieve instances of UITableViewCell, not for StoryBoard.

Comment: thanks for this i have found the "identity" now for the cell. But if you look at the section "Layout The View Controllers" the  4th picture down shows View Controller with Title and Identifier. I cannot see this in my Xcode to set the Identifier for the view....or am i still doing something wrong.... "Switch to the Attributes Inspector and enter “task” for the view’s Identifier. This will be used later to load this view in c# code." Where do i set this "task"

Comment: So for this issue you already have an answer) This is now called Storyboard ID as you write in your question.